# Pygame PixelArray separate pixel modification too slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pixel

I am trying to make 3d game using Pygame and Cython but modifying each pixel of  PixelArray separately is very slow (it takes 60 ms on 400*400 PixelArray). 
I am using this line to modify the color of the pixel:

```
pixelArray[x,y] = 0xFF00FF
```

I tried using integer instead of the hexadecimal value but there is no noticeable difference.
My function for changing pixel uses the line shown above:

```
cdef void paint_pixel(zArray,pixelArray,int x,int y,int z,color):
    if x < len(zArray) and y < len(zArray[0]):
        if (not x < 0) and (not y < 0):
            if zArray[x][y] > z or zArray[x][y] == -1:
                zArray[x][y] = z
                pixelArray[x,y] = 0xFF00FF
```

This will be called at least once for each pixel on the PixelArray.

Is there any way to change each pixel separately faster?

Additional information:
I am using Python 3.4.4 with Cython and Pygame. I would like to avoid using Numpy.

Comment: Z order culling is usually handled by the graphics library.  It there a reason you are rewriting it?

Comment: I am rewriting Z order culling because I want to make 3D game that won't depend on OpenGL and Pygame is library for 2D graphics so it doesn't have Z order culling.

Comment: As much as I love pygame, it isnt really suited for 3d.  Have you looked at Panda3D?

Comment: No. My only problem with pygame is the slow separate pixel change, everything else is fine.

Comment: @Alven You're making it very hard for your self if you want to program in Python and not use numpy. Pure Python isn't very fast iterating though large arrays, which is why numpy was created and is widely used. Pygame has great compatibility with numpy (such as [`pygame.surfarray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html)). If you really don't want to use numpy, then [extend your function (that iterates and manipulates all pixels) with pure C instead](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/extending.html)

Comment: @Alven Also, could you show us the code with your loop? 60ms sounds a lot. I also feel like the two first if statements should be able to be remove. Many unnecessary checks in such tight loop is really bad for performance.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Whole loop (counting all checks) takes 85 ms approximately. After removing the pixelArray modification line, it takes only 25 ms and I know how make those zArray faster. This function is in module that is then cythonized and compiled so loops themselves aren't the problem. As I said, my only problem is the slow PixelArray modification.

Comment: The reason I asked for the loops is just to see how your algorithm actually works. Because you cannot make PixelArray assignment faster (unless you convert it using `newPixelArray = numpy.array(pixelArray, dtype=numpy.uint16)` which half the time), so if you don't want to use numpy, you'll have to make changes to your algorithm. For example, if you remove the checks (change your loop so they aren't necessary), cache the zArray access and pre-calculate constants before the loop (`len(zArray)` and `len(zArray[0])`) you might gain enough speed.

Comment: That means I must stop using PixelArray and switch to other ways (BufferProxy maybe)?

Comment: Some possible ideas. I notice that in your `paint_pixel` function that `pixelArray` has no type. Typing it as some sort of memoryview (e.g. `int[:] pixelArray`) might be helpful to increase performance. Second, if you are calling `paint_pixel` from the python side over and over in a loop, that might be slow too (have a `paint_pixels` function instead that takes in all of the data in an array). Also as a side note, if you are already using cython, you might as well embrace SDL cython bindings. I have personally been using the ones found [here](https://gist.github.com/krischer/4219808).

Answer (score 1):

The `pygame.PixelArray` module is how pygame offers you a way to alter a surface's pixels (or the `pygame.surfarray` module but that is dependent on numpy) and deviating from that will most likely result in costly conversions that'll probably cost more than you gain.

Here is the alternatives you have.

1. Use a 3D library. Pygame doesn't have support for many 3D features
   so you'll have to create them on your own. Creating them in pure
   python will most likely not be fast enough.
2. Use pygame with PyOpenGL. Using your graphics card for graphic calculation is much faster.
3. Use numpy for large numerical calculations. Pygame has great support for numpy and numpy is a well optimized numerical library for large data sets.
4. Change your algorithm. Pre-calculate constants, remove checks from the inner loop, don't use functions to alter a single pixel (you exceptionally rarely change just one pixel and each function call in python gives you a slight overhead), cache values (each access to an array or member access costs in python) and maybe try to assign your data to the pixel array in chunks (since each assignment requires a conversion of the data). Doing this might speed it up enough.
5. Use C/C++ instead. Python is great but has its limitations. If you want to create a 3D-game which runs in 60 fps without third-party libraries, then Python will not be sufficient.